# Optimize a query or suggest LINQ equivalent

Tags: mysql, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

I have a table containing columns date_trans, time_trans, price. After select query, I want to add a new column "Count" which will be calculated as the consecutive equal values of price column and the previous rows having consecutive equal prices will be removed from the final result. See the expected output:

```
date_trans  time_trans  price   **Count**    
2011-02-22  09:39:59    58.02   1
2011-02-22  09:40:03    58.1    *ROW WILL BE REMOVED
2011-02-22  09:40:07    58.1    *ROW WILL BE REMOVED
2011-02-22  09:40:08    58.1    3
2011-02-22  09:40:10    58.15   1
2011-02-22  09:40:10    58.1    *ROW WILL BE REMOVED
2011-02-22  09:40:14    58.1    2
2011-02-22  09:40:24    58.15   1
2011-02-22  09:40:24    58.18   *ROW WILL BE REMOVED
2011-02-22  09:40:24    58.18   *ROW WILL BE REMOVED
2011-02-22  09:40:24    58.18   3
2011-02-22  09:40:24    58.15   1
```

Please suggest a sql query or LINQ expression to select from the table

Currently, I can do it be a select query and looping through all the selected rows but when selecting millions of rows it takes hours.

My current code:

```
    string query = @"SELECT date_trans, time_trans,  price
                            FROM tbl_data 
                         WHERE date_trans BETWEEN '2011-02-22' AND '2011-10-21'
                        AND time_trans BETWEEN '09:30:00' AND '16:00:00'";

            DataTable dt = oUtil.GetDataTable(query);

            DataColumn col = new DataColumn("Count", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add(col);

            int priceCount = 1;
            for (int count = 0; count < dt.Rows.Count; count++)
            {
                double price = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[count]["price"]);
                double priceNext = (count == dt.Rows.Count - 1) ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[count + 1]["price"]);
                if (price == priceNext)
                {
                    priceCount++;
                    dt.Rows.RemoveAt(count);
                    count--;
                }
                else
                {
                    dt.Rows[count]["Count"] = priceCount;
                    priceCount = 1;
                }
            }
```

Comment: I think it's possible with analytic functions in SQL. It's late so my brain isn't quite able to process it all now, but when I'm rested, I'll come back and see if you still need an answer. But I think you should start by looking at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854854/getting-all-consecutive-rows-differing-by-certain-value) and how it uses the analytic functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an interesting one. I think what you need would be something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(date_trans), MAX(time_trans), MAX(price), COUNT(*)
FROM
    (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY price ORDER BY date_trans, time_trans) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY date_trans, time_trans) AS grp
    FROM transactions) grps
GROUP BY grp
```

Found the solution here: http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server/solution-to-the-t-sql-puzzle-grouping-consecutive-rows-with-a-common-element

**UPDATE**

The grouping column needs to also include "price", otherwise groups might not be unique. One more thing is that the date and time column should be combined into a datetime column so the max datetime value is correct in groups that start near the end of one day and end on the beginning of the next.
Here's the corrected query.

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(date_trans AS DATETIME) + CAST(time_trans AS DATETIME)) , MAX(price), COUNT(*)
FROM
    (SELECT *, 
        CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY price ORDER BY date_trans, time_trans) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY date_trans, time_trans) AS NVARCHAR(255)) + '-' + CAST(price AS NVARCHAR(255)) AS grp
    FROM transactions
    ORDER BY date_trans, time_trans) grps
GROUP BY grp
```

The query might be more optimal with the 'grp' column as a byte array or bigint instead of a nvarchar. Also you mentioned a 'volume' column that you probably want to sum within the group.

Comment: Thank you Pawel. You're almost there.
Please download the csv, import into database and check. Some records are showing duplicate. Please help me by improving your query.
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B_fUxFgeU2-dc3hfR2JrR2ExQ2s

The columns are date_trans, time_trans, price, volume in the CSV

Comment: Right. Updated the answer. I didn't notice it before but you tagged your question 'mysql' but you meant 'mssql', right?

Comment: I have planned to use IDENTITY and order by that column to get more accurate results.
Can you suggest me a format file and sql bulk insert query for the csv import in MS SQL? The csv (.txt) contains 10 columns but I need first 4 columns. There will be a IDENTITY column in the table. The format file is difficult for me because of the date format in the csv file. The date format is British (dd/mm/yyyy). Here is the csv file.
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B3QJE7P_Z7bWVW42eWdqT2t4YVE

Comment: No need for the query. I'd recommend using Sql Server Management Studio which has a nice data import wizard. You shouldn't have a problem with clicking your way through the whole operation.